# Shortcut for a regular command in linux , not using alias

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

I am a rookie when it comes to Linux.

I have a regular requirement to grep for specific text in a huge list of files on terminal.
I use `grep -i "<text>" *.txt`

Requirement is cursor to stay between `""` once I apply a shortcut key.
I used a simple python script to run this shortcut on securecrt. Recently I moved to Tabby which is not having option to run script.
So how do I do this within the terminal itself. ( I don't have admin rights to Ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

**Bash function**

The most flexible way in such a case is to create a small bash function:

```
mygrep () {
   grep -i "$@" *.txt
}
```

and include that in your `~/.bashrc` file so it is available anytime you open a terminal. Then, `mygrep` (you can change that to anything you prefer) will be a command available to you, and can be invoked as:

```
mygrep "Text to search"
```

**Alias**

Only if the command can be written with your variable argument as the last one, an alias can be used instead. With `grep`, it can be done:

```
alias mygrep='grep *.txt -i -e'
```

Answer (score 0):

write this command to your terminal:

```
alias gp='read gpvar && grep -i "$gpvar" *.txt'
```

Then you can simply run `gp` and the terminal will ask you for input, the text to search and give you the grep output.

you can include this line of code into your .bashrc as well so that there's no need to run it every time you connect to the server

Comment: Why are you searching a specific file named `.vimrc` and why are you assuming that file exists in the current directory? Also, there is no need for `cat` even to do what your command does, and this won't work as you have it since because you encolsed the alias in `"`, the `$gpvar` will be expanded before the alias runs and will therefore always be empty. You need: `alias gp='read gpvar && grep -i "$gpvar" .vimrc'`

Comment: I mentioned that .vimrc should be replaced as this is an example @terdon, it worked for me idk why it didn't work for you, your version is much neater and more efficient I'll include it in my answer thanks

Comment: It's an example yes, but the OP asked for a command that searches all files in the current directory whose name end with `.txt`, so it is strange that you show something so different. And it can't have worked if you were using `"`. It will work with single quotes, yes.